# How to display related data in the current table?

Tags: sql-server

There are three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE T1_HUMAN (
    Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    Surname varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    TypePhone <???>, 
    PhoneNumber <???> 
)

CREATE TABLE T2_PHONE (
    Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    TypePhone varchar(max) NOT NULL, 
    PhoneNumber char(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    [Name] <???>,
    Surname <???>
)

CREATE TABLE T3 (
     T1_PhoneNumber int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES T1_HUMAN(Id),
     T2_PhoneNumber int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES T2_PHONE(Id),
     PRIMARY KEY(T1_PhoneNumber, T2_PhoneNumber) 
)
```

As you sees this relationship is Many-to-Many - one person can have more than one phone and one phone number can use several people.

I need the following:

- If a specific phone number (T2_PHONE.Id) is used by several people,
  this data (Name, Surname) should be displayed in the appropriate
  fields of the T2_PHONE table.
- If a specific person (T1_HUMAN.Id) uses several phone numbers, this
  data (TypePhone, PhoneNumber) needs to be displayed in the
  appropriate fields of the T1_HUMAN table.

**How do I change tables to meet the above requirements?**

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're going for, I don't think you should do this... Your first table should have only information related to each person (an id, name, whatever), your second table should have information only related to phone numbers (id, phone number, whatever else) and your third table (the bridge) would just have the person id and the phone id. Don't insert the names into the t2_phone table or the t1_human table... Use joins _when necessary_. Or a view. Inserting the data into the table itself makes things more complicated when data changes.

Comment: I agree, this design breaks the basic principles of database normalisation. If the person changes their name (e.g. they get married) you have to update the name in many places, not just one.

Comment: I understand that this is a difficult task, but I need an answer. Please ignore further issues with the operation of such a database. Just tell me how you can implement it.

Comment: It's not a "difficult" task per se. It's an inadvisable task... You can theoretically do this (for example, with an initial update then triggers for when any table inserts/updates/deletes data... or by having a specific procedure for inserting or updating that does what you want and ONLY inserting/updating with that), but it is more complicated and far less sensible than the usual (normalised) approach. Whoever is telling you that you need to do this probably doesn't know much about relational databases; I would push back against it.

Comment: @ZLK Ok. Thank you!

Comment: Aso: Which sql server version are you using?

Comment: @George Menoutis - Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the tables is fine as it is.

What you are requesting is strange, and not really clear. For example, if one person uses 2 phones, you will have 2 pairs of (typephone,phonenumber): you cannot put them in one row.

I suspect you either want comma-seperated values, or multiple fields. If this is the case, please do *NOT* alter the current correct structure of your tables and violate the first normal form. Instead, if you must be able to see these data, create views that depend on those tables.

We will be happy to provide an answer if you clear up what you exactly want. Eg, how do you want your queries to look in case of persons A and B sharing both phone1 and phone2?

Comment: This is the task that was set before me. I can not answer you question because I do not understand it myself. Therefore, I seek help to explain to me what is required of me and helped to realize it.

Comment: Do you have a specification text?